# Build a UrlTree from Vec<String>

Tags: algorithm, web, struct, rust, tree

i'm need to make url tree struct, like a sitemap.
Input: Vec - list of url
Expected Output: struct with nested hierarhy of url's, from root to endpoints.

**Does it already existed crate or i need to make it myself?**

Input:

```
{
   "https://exapmle.com",
   "https://exapmle.com/aa",
   "https://exapmle.com/ab",
   "https://exapmle.com/v",
   "https://exapmle.com/zac",
   "https://exapmle.com/zac/acf",
   "https://exapmle.com/zac/acf/adr",
   "https://exapmle.com/zac/axx"
}
```

Output:

```
UrlTree {
    root: "https://exapmle.com",
    Nodes: {
        {
            node: "aa",
            Nodes: None,
        },
        {
            node: "ab",
            Nodes: None,
        },
        {
            node: "v",
            Nodes: None,
        },
        {
            node: "zac",
            Nodes: {
                       {
                            node: "acf",
                            Nodes: {
                                       node: "adr",
                                       Nodes: None,
                                   }   
                       },
                       {
                            node: "axx",
                            Nodes: None,
                       }
                   }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While it's doubtful that you'll find a crate that *exactly* matches your particular use case, it shouldn't be hard to create a data structure that does what you want.

Comment: In your desired output it's hard to tell what is the type of the `Nodes` field - it sort of look likes a dict, but its keys seem to be embedded in values. You could map the subnodes as a `HashMap` whose keys are strings and whose values are nodes corresponding to those strings, such as [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a126e4df595daf88d6226b64c8286224). The precise design will also depend on exactly what you want to _do_ with the resulting tree.

Comment: You can look for radix tree or prefix tree implementations on https://crates.io/. A quick search turned up this one, which looks reasonable: https://docs.rs/radix_trie/0.2.1/radix_trie/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have to code something yourself.
While you could use a radix trie, as mentioned by Sven Marnach, you will have the problem that it might split on a folder name and not only the /. Abc/df and abd/df would be saved as (an, c/df, d/df).

Do making something yourself, you have to ask,  how big your input size will be, the length or your vec, how performant does your code need to be?

If performance is not that big of a problem then a vec of struts would be finde. On each insert just check if the current folder is already in the hashmap and add or go down a step. After you have build the structure map it to your desired output.

If you need something performant, you could implement something like the radix trie, the structure is not too hard to implement sinceyyou only have to care about splitting on "/" you could use this as inspiration [https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RadixTree.html](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/RadixTree.html).